# gigahorse CPU plotting error payload:allShortcutsEnabled:false

Tags: python, ubuntu, cryptocurrency

I am running Ubuntu Server 22.04 and I've installed the madmax farmer and am trying to use the gigahorse cpu plotting on ubuntu. I am getting this error when trying to run it and have been unable to find an answer anywhere!

```
./chia_plot: line 1: payload:allShortcutsEnabled:false: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download the binary from the raw file, not the HTML. You should have a binary that is a few megabytes in size. The HTML will be smaller than the executable binary.

```
$ wget https://github.com/madMAx43v3r/chia-gigahorse/raw/master/cpu-plotter/linux/x86_64/chia_plot
```

Then you need to make the binary executable:

```
$ chmod +x chia_plot
```